Non-symmetric bump function
I am trying to create a smooth bump function $f(x;a,b,c,k_1,k_2)$ satisfying the following properties:

$f$ is smooth (can be relaxed)
$f$ is supported on $[a,c]$.
$f$ is increasing on $(a,b)$.
$f$ is decreasing on $(b,c)$.
$f(b) = 1$.
$k_1$ and $k_2$ are parameters that control the decay rates on the left and right side of $b$ (I know this is a bit vague but hopefully it makes sense).

For simplicity, it can be assumed that $a=0, c=1$ and $0<b<1$. Essentially, I want it to look like a non-symmetric version of the standard bump function $\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}\exp(\frac{1}{x^2-1})$, where the location of the peak can be controlled. If anyone has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated.

You can multiply that function by powers of $x$, rescale it, and shift it around to somewhat replicate what you're looking for. I presume you mean $c=1$ as well.

A rough idea for the implementation of $a,b,c$ is here, but I'm not sure how best to handle the $k_1,k_2$ bits (which is probably the most difficult part anyways you're concerned with). But it's a start I guess.

@CameronWilliams A function like that will always be symmetric about the peak. I appreciate the suggestion though, I hadn’t considered multiplying by powers of x. Oh yep, good catch! Will edit now

@PrincessEev oh wow, that’s sick! I love a good Desmos implementation. That will definitely be useful for me to build off. Thanks heaps!

@PrincessEev Perhaps this can be used to implement the non-symmetric nature?

You can achieve the desired skewing, location, and domain by suitably generalizing the rational function inside the exponential:  for instance, consider
$$h(x;a,b,c) = \frac{(x-b)^2}{(x-a)(x-c)}, \quad a < x < c. \tag{1}$$  Then define
$$f(x;a,b,c) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \in (-\infty, a] \cup [c, \infty) \\ e^{h(x;a,b,c)}, & x \in (a, b) \cup (b, c) \\ 1, & x = b. \end{cases} \tag{2}$$
This gives the desired bump function behavior except for the "decay rates" $k_1, k_2$.   We can modify $(2)$ to incorporate a "symmetric decay factor" $k$ by writing $f(x;a,b,c,k) = e^{k h(x;a,b,c)}$ in the nontrivial case; here, for increasing $k > 0$, the function decays faster as one approaches $a$ or $c$.  But what you really want are two factors that can be controlled for the intervals $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ separately.  A primitive way to do this is to write
$$h(x;a,b,c,k_1,k_2) = \begin{cases} k_1 h(x;a,b,c), & a < x < b \\ k_2 h(x;a,b,c), & b < x < c \end{cases} \tag{3}$$ and compute $f$ accordingly, but I suspect that with more thought, one can devise a single rational function that captures the entire set of desired behaviors without needing to resort to a piecewise definition.

Ideally, I would love a non-piecewise definition, but this still works really well for my use case, definitely better than anything I had come up with myself. Thank you!
